# Typescript react generic service with functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I was trying to build a generic service to load from an endpoint. It works, but I would like to use

```
const useService = <T>(endpoint: string) => {...}
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to type a function with this syntax, or sugar?

```
export interface ISubscription<T> {
  payload: T[];
}

type Service<T> = Service<ISubscription<T>>;

const useService = function<T>(endpoint: string) {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<Service<T>>({
    status: 'loading'
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    API.axiosClient.get<ISubscription<T>>(`xxx/${endpoint}`)
      .then(response => {
        setResult({ status: 'loaded', payload: { payload: response.data.payload }  });
      })
      .catch(error => setResult({ status: 'error', error }));
  }, [endpoint]);

  return result;
};
```

where `Service` is

```
interface ServiceInit {
    status: 'init';
}
interface ServiceLoading {
    status: 'loading';
}
export interface ServiceLoaded<T> {
    status: 'loaded';
    payload: T;
}
interface ServiceError {
    status: 'error';
    error: Error;
}

export type Service<T> =
  | ServiceInit
  | ServiceLoading
  | ServiceLoaded<T>
  | ServiceError;
```

Comment: It certainly does, thanks. I didn't realise there was an `extends`